# PHP - Dynamic 365 - Return after Posting a Record

Tags: php, php-curl, dynamics-365

I am able to successfully post a record to dynamic 365 using PHP CURL. After the record is posted there is no return after the information is inserted into the entities. I can run a search based on the information in the form, but I would really I to get the GUID of the record that has been inserted.

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    $URL_String = $_SESSION['crm365']['rest_api_url'] . 'my individual entity';
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $URL_String,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST', 
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($add_indivudual), 
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'OData-MaxVersion: 4.0',
            'OData-Version: 4.0',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json',
            $_SESSION['crm365']['access_token']
          ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: and what do you get from `var_dump($response);` afterwards?

Comment: There nothing returned. That is the first thing I checked.

Comment: You need to investigate further that API or leverage a already existing package. A quick search got me to this [one](https://github.com/RobbeR/RDynamics) where you can see that there might be [some not so common particularities](https://github.com/RobbeR/RDynamics/blob/15d3320bcf20404201e124d2bf7dbfe3c74448b1/RDynamics.php#L152) on how you are supposed to fetch information.

Comment: @BennyArgo var_dump() always prints *SOMETHING*, what does it print?

Comment: @hanshenrik, It returns a null value but I can confirm the record is being created.

Comment: @BennyArgo worst part is, i don't even really believe you. maybe it returns something pretty close to null: it can return `bool(false)` and it can return `string(3) "NULL"`, but i find it hard to believe that it actually returns null. but if it does, then your curl_setopt_array() is probably failing. add a `var_dump( curl_setopt_array($curl,...));`, what does that give you?